# styling Javascript alert box with css

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to style this javascript alert box but no luck, i was wondering if yall could help me.

```
document.getElementById('RedirBut').onclick=function(){alert('тут написан твой текст');}; alert.id = text11;
```

Comment: The box shown from `alert` is not able to be styled with CSS.

Comment: you could make your own dialog box with custom styling as an alternative